# Track Chosen Playing Card During Faro Shuffles

Tags: java

I'm building a Java app that tracks a chosen playing card during an "Out" faro shuffle. I've been a magician for a long time and this just seemed like a fun thing to do, and while I've seen apps/sites that will show you the order of an out faro after every shuffle, they don't specifically track a chosen card.

I sort of have a brute force method for every shuffle. I only have two shuffles completed, but the rest of the shuffles would basically be copy/paste, which goes against DRY, but every shuffle has a specific order, so I'm not sure how I could ensure that order remains the same after every iteration. Maybe store each iteration in its own list?

Oh and an out faro is when the cards are perfectly weaved, but the top and bottom cards remain the same. So a perfect 26/26 split and then a perfect weave.

If anyone has any better ideas let me know. The code isn't very pretty yet and I have refactoring to do.

```
package Tracker;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NewDeckOrder {

private ArrayList<String> bicycleDeckOrder;

public NewDeckOrder() {

    String[] suitesFirstHalf = {"Hearts", "Clubs"};
    String[] valuesFirstHalf = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

    String[] suitesSecondHalf = {"Diamonds", "Spades"};
    String[] valuesSecondHalf = {"King", "Queen", "Jack", "10", "9", 
"8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "Ace"};

    bicycleDeckOrder = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String deckFirstSuites : suitesFirstHalf) {
        for (String deckFirstValues : valuesFirstHalf) {
            bicycleDeckOrder.add(deckFirstValues + " of " + 
deckFirstSuites);
        }
    }

    for (String deckSecondSuites : suitesSecondHalf) {
        for (String deckSecondValues : valuesSecondHalf) {
            bicycleDeckOrder.add(deckSecondValues + " of " + 
deckSecondSuites);
        }
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> getList() {
    return bicycleDeckOrder;
}
@Override
public String  toString() {
    return "New Deck Order " + bicycleDeckOrder;
}
}


package Tracker;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class OutFaro {
private ArrayList<String> oneShuffle;
private ArrayList<String> twoShuffles;
private ArrayList<String> threeShuffles;


public ArrayList<String> getOneShuffle() {
    return oneShuffle;
}

public void setOneShuffle(ArrayList<String> oneShuffle) {
    this.oneShuffle = oneShuffle;
}

public ArrayList<String> firstShuffle(ArrayList<String> newDeckOrder) 
{

    ArrayList<String> first26 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> last26 = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < newDeckOrder.size() - 26; i++) {
        first26.add(newDeckOrder.get(i));
    }

    for(int j = 26; j < newDeckOrder.size(); j++) {
        last26.add(newDeckOrder.get(j));
    }


    // One Shuffle
    oneShuffle = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < first26.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < last26.size(); j++) {
            oneShuffle.add(first26.get(i));
            oneShuffle.add(last26.get(j));
            i++;

        }
    }

    return oneShuffle;
}

public ArrayList<String> getTwoShuffles() {
    return twoShuffles;
}

public void setTwoShuffles(ArrayList<String> twoShuffles) {
    this.twoShuffles = twoShuffles;
}

public ArrayList<String> secondShuffle(ArrayList<String> 
firstShuffleResults) {

    ArrayList<String> first26SecondShuffle = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> last26SecondShuffle = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < firstShuffleResults.size() - 26; i++) {
        first26SecondShuffle.add(firstShuffleResults.get(i));
    }

    for(int j = 26; j < firstShuffleResults.size(); j++) {
        last26SecondShuffle.add(firstShuffleResults.get(j));
    }

    // Second Shuffle
    twoShuffles = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < first26SecondShuffle.size() - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < last26SecondShuffle.size() - 1; j++) {
            twoShuffles.add(first26SecondShuffle.get(i));
            twoShuffles.add(last26SecondShuffle.get(j));
            i++;

        }
    }

    return twoShuffles;

}
}


import Tracker.NewDeckOrder;
import Tracker.OutFaro;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    NewDeckOrder deckOrder;
    // Bicycle new deck order
    System.out.println("Current deck order:");
    NewDeckOrder newDeckOrder = new NewDeckOrder();
    System.out.println(newDeckOrder.toString());

    // One out faro
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the card you wish to track: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cardToTrack = input.nextLine();

    deckOrder = new NewDeckOrder();

    int cardsPosition = 0;
    ArrayList<String> temp = deckOrder.getList();
    if (temp.contains(cardToTrack)) {
        cardsPosition += temp.indexOf(cardToTrack) + 1;
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + cardToTrack + " starting position is " + cardsPosition + ".");
    System.out.println("\n" + "Performing one out faro.");

    OutFaro outFaro = new OutFaro();

    String[] firstHalfSuites = new String[]{"Hearts", "Clubs"};
    String[] firstHalfValues = new String[]{"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

    String[] secondHalfSuites = new String[]{"Diamonds", "Spades"};
    String[] secondHalfValues = new String[]{"King", "Queen", "Jack", "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "Ace"};

    outFaro.setOneShuffle(outFaro.firstShuffle(newDeckOrder.getList()));

   // System.out.println("\n" + "First shuffle results: " + outFaro.getOneShuffle());

    outFaro.setTwoShuffles(outFaro.secondShuffle(outFaro.getOneShuffle()));


    int cardAfterOneShuffle = 0;
    if (outFaro.getOneShuffle().contains(cardToTrack)) {
        cardAfterOneShuffle += outFaro.firstShuffle(newDeckOrder.getList()).indexOf(cardToTrack) + 1;

    }
    System.out.println("\n" + "After one shuffle, your card is at number " + cardAfterOneShuffle);

    int cardAfterTwoShuffles = 0;

    // System.out.println("\n" + "Second shuffle results: " + outFaro.getTwoShuffles());

    if (outFaro.getTwoShuffles().contains(cardToTrack)) {
        cardAfterTwoShuffles += outFaro.getTwoShuffles().indexOf(cardToTrack) + 1;

    }

    System.out.println("\n" + "After two shuffles, your card is at number " + cardAfterTwoShuffles);


}


}
```

Comment: Why don't you make an object representing a card with 2 fields: suit and value, and just keep track of the deck with some data structure? Then, for each shuffle you can simply perform the same operations on that data structure.

Comment: This is sort of what I was thinking as I was typing out the question. After every shuffle I could store the result of that shuffle in its own ArrayList so I could access the target card. I think I could use switch statements after every shuffle.

Comment: I'm cleaning up a lot of this code. I've been doing this in weird sprints while watching Netflix and not really paying attention. It was basically code vomit. Lots of unnecessary variables. I will post a better version soonish. Thanks for your help Meepo!

Comment: Also, if you want to simply keep track of a card, simply have the deck shuffle, and then have the user enter in the card they want the position of. Then using the suit and the value (by parsing the string) simply loop through the deck array and find that card!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, seems like every time I post on stackoverflow I end up finding the solution myself. Maybe it's just typing it out and working through it? Anyways, I found a much much much less convoluted way to do this recursively. I am actually proud of myself because I solved this 100% on my own so I guess my Java/programming knowledge is at a decent spot.

I don't think the code is 100% perfect yet, but far better than the "code vomit" solution I had before. Thank you to Meepo for kind of guiding me.

OutFaro Class that has the shuffling logic:

```
package Tracker;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class OutFaro {
private ArrayList<String> shuffleResults;
private int shuffleCounter;


public ArrayList<String> getOneShuffle() {
    return shuffleResults;
}

public ArrayList<String> outFaro(ArrayList<String> newDeckOrder, int numberOfFaros) {

    shuffleResults = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    while (shuffleCounter != numberOfFaros) {

        for (int i = 0; i < newDeckOrder.size() - 26; i++) {
            for (int j = 26; j < newDeckOrder.size(); j++) {
                temp.add(newDeckOrder.get(i));
                temp.add(newDeckOrder.get(j));
                i++;
            }
        }

        shuffleCounter++;
        if (shuffleCounter == numberOfFaros) {
            shuffleResults = temp;
        } else {
            outFaro(temp, numberOfFaros);
        }

    }
    return shuffleResults;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "OutFaro{" +
            "oneShuffle=" + shuffleResults +
            '}';
}
}
```

New Deck Order class that builds the new deck:

```
package Tracker;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NewDeckOrder {

private ArrayList<String> bicycleDeckOrder;

public ArrayList<String> americanNewDeckOrder() {

    String[] suitesFirstHalf = {"Hearts", "Clubs"};
    String[] valuesFirstHalf = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

    String[] suitesSecondHalf = {"Diamonds", "Spades"};
    String[] valuesSecondHalf = {"King", "Queen", "Jack", "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "Ace"};

    bicycleDeckOrder = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String deckFirstSuites : suitesFirstHalf) {
        for (String deckFirstValues : valuesFirstHalf) {
            bicycleDeckOrder.add(deckFirstValues + " of " + deckFirstSuites);
        }
    }

    for (String deckSecondSuites : suitesSecondHalf) {
        for (String deckSecondValues : valuesSecondHalf) {
            bicycleDeckOrder.add(deckSecondValues + " of " + deckSecondSuites);
        }
    }
    return bicycleDeckOrder;
}


public ArrayList<String> getBicycleDeckOrder() {
    return bicycleDeckOrder;
}

public void setBicycleDeckOrder(ArrayList<String> bicycleDeckOrder) {
    this.bicycleDeckOrder = bicycleDeckOrder;
}

@Override
public String  toString() {
    return "New Deck Order " + bicycleDeckOrder;
}
}
```

Client code:

```
 import Tracker.NewDeckOrder;
 import Tracker.OutFaro;
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int cardAfterOneShuffle = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Bicycle new deck order
    System.out.println("Current deck order:");
    NewDeckOrder newDeckOrder = new NewDeckOrder();
    newDeckOrder.setBicycleDeckOrder(newDeckOrder.americanNewDeckOrder());
    System.out.println(newDeckOrder.getBicycleDeckOrder().toString());

    // User input
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the card you wish to track: ");
    String cardToTrack = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("\nHow many out Faro's would you like to shuffle?");
    int numberOfFaros = input.nextInt();


    int cardsPosition = 0;

    if (newDeckOrder.americanNewDeckOrder().contains(cardToTrack)) {
        cardsPosition += newDeckOrder.americanNewDeckOrder().indexOf(cardToTrack) + 1;
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + cardToTrack + " starting position is " + cardsPosition + ".");

    OutFaro outFaro = new OutFaro();

    outFaro.outFaro(newDeckOrder.getBicycleDeckOrder(), numberOfFaros);

    System.out.println("\n" + "After " + numberOfFaros + " shuffles the deck order is: " + outFaro.getOneShuffle());


    if (outFaro.getOneShuffle().contains(cardToTrack)) {
        cardAfterOneShuffle += outFaro.getOneShuffle().indexOf(cardToTrack) + 1;

    }

    System.out.println("\n" + "After " + numberOfFaros + " shuffles your card is at number " + cardAfterOneShuffle);


}


}
```

Comment: Good job, I'm happy you figured it out yourself! This code looks much cleaner and less redundant